# Manage Content and Structure Custom Errors After Upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-collection, web-config, spwebconfigmodification

I upgraded to SharePoint 2010 and now I can not get access to the content and structure section located under "Site Actions". The runtime error appears telling me that an Application error occurred on the server, then a custom-error page appears.

```
    <configuration>
         <system.web>
           <custom Errors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error message that appears in your ULS logs?

Comment: This may happen if you had any of the Fab 40 templates installed that you tried to migrate. If you go to the Upgrade status in Central Administration did if fail?

Comment: Yes i checked the upgrade status and realized that there were some fails and warnings. this is not a good sign as it might relate to my issue.